# How to access the variables that are in void onCreate class from another class (both are under activity subclass)?

Tags: android, scope

I am trying to access some of the onCreate class variables from another class that is under activity class, for example

```
..Acivity class(..)
        Class onCreate(..){
              Final int intItemNo = 0;

        } 

        Class testing(){
             //some commands here, will need access to the intItemNo above.
        } 
 };
```

Comment: `Final int intItemNo = 0;` this is local variable in `onCreate() method, not class variable.

Comment: So how can I declear it in a way that it can be accessed in the other class class testing()

Comment: your stuffs above just don't make any sense to me, are you trying to say `onCreate()` and `testing()` are classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the variable definition outside of the onCreate Class. I am assuming this code is from an activity class so onCreate is really a method not a class. It does not change the answer though. If it is not, onCreate is not a good name for class as it conflicts with an android method.

```
public class1 extends Activity {

    Final int intItemNo;

    public void  onCreate(..){
         intItemNo = 0;
    } 

    Class testing(){
         intItemNo = 1;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I am not confused between classes and methods. I know the difference. the issue I have is I was trying to get some vars that are located inside onCreate to be used on testing class.